# Custom properties are not being saved immediately to Exchange Server in Outlook desktop 2016

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

My Outlook web add-in saves emails to an external application.Upon save, it will also write some custom information to exchange server using Office.js's `customProps.saveAsync();`. So next time the user open the same email, the add-in will look up the properties and if it is not null will remind the user the email has been saved.

Work like a charm in web browser(Office 365).

However in Windows Outlook desktop, the function performs strangely. If I save the email and then immediately move the email to another folder. The `customProps.saveAsync();` will fail(nothing saved to exchange server). However, if I re-launch the add-in on the email before moving out to another folder, the custom info will be saved successfully.

Seems to me on Outlook desktop the custom properties will not be written to the exchange server immediately, instead, it will wait until it is being triggered(re-launch add-in etc I do not know the exact mechanism). However, if the email being moved to another folder right after being saved in an add-in, the pending function will be lost.

I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a7417d1-8af8-453f-bce0-584b7f79b0c1/app-for-outlook-ews-request-failed-with-item-id-returned-by-itemsaveasync-on-compose-new-message?forum=appsforoffice) describing seemingly similar behavior. So I then turned off the "cache" mode in outlook but the problem persisted.

I also tried using EWS's API to perform the "save custom properties", but the problem still persisted.

Am I missing somethinghere or it is Outlook desktop's bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not missing something - this is definitely a bug in Outlook Desktop. Thank you for reporting the issue. We are investigating and will work on a fix as quickly as we can.

**As a workaround in the interim**, you can switch messages within the same folder in order to trigger a save. The workaround you found of re-opening an Add-in may also work.